# How do I add a cronjob to a makefile?

Tags: unix, makefile, cron

How do I add a cronjob to a makefile so when I compile a C program, I add a cron job to crontab so that program gets executed every minute:

Cron job I am trying to add:

```
* * * * * /Users/jenna/desktop/ && ./myProgram command_line_arg1
```

how do I add this to a make file ?

Comment: What is your program really doing? Some cleanup? Some backups? Why do you want to run it every minute? What happens if its execution lasts more than a minute (that could happen on a loaded system)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Nothing serious. Just a school assignment where I append the current time to a file. Cron job would merely add the current time every minute....

Answer (score 0):

I believe **it is a bad idea to add a *`crontab`* job from a `Makefile`**. Adding a `cron` job is a sysadmin issue. Compiling your program is for a developer's hat.

If you insist on doing that, you might use `crontab -l > mycrontab`  to list the current crontab jobs, then appending with

```
echo '* * * * * cd /Users/jenna/desktop/ && ./myProgram command_line_arg1' \
     >> mycrontab
```

you probably want to make that more robust (perhaps use `grep` or `awk`) to avoid the appending if the crontab already contains that. BTW, you probably want to use `$HOME/Desktop`  (and even that might not work on a French configured user, it would be `$HOME/Bureau`).

Then, set the new crontab with `crontab mycrontab`

At last, running something every minute seems suspicious to me. What is your program doing?

I would suggest to at the very least prompt the user before updating his/her `crontab` file....

Perhaps you want the [at](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm) command....